# code is excecuted even when the condition is not satisfied

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i made a code to validate the unique id to be atleast 4 characters , atleast 1 lower case character and atleast 1 number

This is the css code

```
<style>

.valid {
  color: green;
}
.invalid {
  color: red;
}
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
}

.button:hover {background-color: #3e8e41}

.button:active {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
#grad {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, #33ccff 10%, #ff99cc 100%);
}
</style>
```

input code

```
<input type="button" class="button"  value="Save" onclick="save_user();" autocomplete="on" />
```

this is the script code

```
<script>

  var tblUsers = document.getElementById('tbl_users_list');
  var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref('users/');
  var rowIndex = 1;
  var uid;
  var childKey;
  var childData;

  databaseRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    childSnapshot.key;
    childSnapshot.val();

   var row = tblUsers.insertRow(rowIndex);
   var cellId = row.insertCell(0);
   var cellName = row.insertCell(1);
   cellId.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childKey));
   cellName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.user_name));
   cellName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.user_name2));

   rowIndex = rowIndex + 1;


    });
  });



function check()
{


 var myInput = document.getElementById("user_name2");
  var letter = document.getElementById("letter");

  var number = document.getElementById("number");
  var length = document.getElementById("length");

  // When the user clicks on the password field, show the message box
  myInput.onfocus = function() {
    document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
  }

  // When the user clicks outside of the password field, hide the message box
  myInput.onblur = function() {
    document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
  }

  // When the user starts to type something inside the password field
  myInput.onkeyup = function() {
    // Validate lowercase letters
    var lowerCaseLetters = /[a-z]/g;
    if(myInput.value.match(lowerCaseLetters)) {  
      letter.classList.remove("invalid");
      letter.classList.add("valid");
    } else {
      letter.classList.remove("valid");
      letter.classList.add("invalid");
    }



    // Validate numbers
    var numbers = /[0-9]/g;
    if(myInput.value.match(numbers)) {  
      number.classList.remove("invalid");
      number.classList.add("valid");
    } else {
      number.classList.remove("valid");
      number.classList.add("invalid");
    }

    // Validate length
    if(myInput.value.length >= 4) {
      length.classList.remove("invalid");
      length.classList.add("valid");
    } else {
      length.classList.remove("valid");
      length.classList.add("invalid");
    }
  }




return true;



}










if(check())
{

  function save_user(){

var user_name = document.getElementById('user_name').value;
   var user_name2 = document.getElementById('user_name2').value;

   uid = firebase.database().ref().child('users').push().key;

   var data = {
    user_id: uid,
    user_name: user_name,
    password: user_name2
   }

   var updates = {};
   updates['/users/' + uid] = data;
   firebase.database().ref().update(updates);

   alert('The user is created successfully!');
   reload_page();

   document.writeln(uid);


  }
}
else{
  alert('condition not satisfied');
}
  function update_user(){
   var user_name = document.getElementById('user_name').value;
   var user_id = document.getElementById('user_id').value;

   var data = {
    user_id: user_id,
    user_name: user_name
   }

   var updates = {};
   updates['/users/' + user_id] = data;
   firebase.database().ref().update(updates);

   alert('The user is updated successfully!');

   reload_page();
  }
```

the validatation process are in the function check()

and the function is returned true

in the main script file it should excecute only when the function check() is true but it excecutes even it is not true

**all i want from this code is that the value should upload in the database only when the function check() is true**
what changes should i make in this code?

Comment: You have `return true` at the end of your `check()` function, so it'll always go in the `if(check())` and save the user

Comment: and also i am facing a error like save_user not a function and the else alert('not satisfied') is excecuted once i open the webpage pls help

Answer (score 0):

You have `return true` at the end. So it returns a true value. So when `if(check())` is checked, it gets a true value. The same output can be achieved by easier code.

Your `save_user()` function is not called when you are clicking the submit button. It's inside an `if` condition.

Comment: i am also facing a error like save_user not a function and the else `alert('not satisfied')` is excecuted once i open the webpage pls help